# Defining bounding shapes or areas using osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I would like to define areas of interest in an area using *osmdroid*. I have multiple `GeoPoint` objects that bound the area. Reading up on *OpenStreetMap*, I found that they define areas. However, this concept seems to be missing from the code. The closes I can find is the `BoundingBoxE6` class. It provides methods I would require, such as building a box from `GeoPoint` objects or checking if a given `GeoPoint` resides inside a `BoundingBoxE6`. Unfortunately, my areas of interest are not always boxes. Some of them are, two dimensionally speaking, circles or hallways which tend to mimic Tetris shapes.

I am aware that the problem can be approached by stacking multiple `BoundingBoxE6` objects to get the shape I desire. But this seems rather unpractical because I would have to either define a class holding a reference of multiple `BoundingBoxE6` objects. Even then, a circular shape could only be approached by a large amount of `BoundingBoxE6` which would be very ineffective in terms of checking for inclusion of a `GeoPoint` for example.

Is there another way to approach this problem? Maybe I have just overlooked a class that could be helpful. I would welcome the input of someone more familiar with *osmdroid*.

Sources:
[osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/#svn/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid)
[`GeoPoint`](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/util/GeoPoint.java), 
[`BoundingBoxE6`](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/util/BoundingBoxE6.java)